# Lost qgis_core.dll

Tags: installation, qgis-2.4

I´ve been working with QGIS 2.4 since two months ago. After doing some changes in my computer, I think I've lost something important for running QGIS 2.4

The message is:

> qgis.exe - System error.
>
> The program can´t start because qgis-core.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem

I reinstalled the 2.4 32 and 64, the 2.2 version and the problem is still there. I can't open QGIS. It shows the first window and crashes.
The QGIS browser works fine....

This is the path of my computer:

> C:\Program Files\Gimp-2.8\bin;C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT

and the python path is:

> C:\Python34\Lib;C:\Python34\DLLs;C:\Python34\Lib\lib-tk;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python34\projects

I don´t know what to do to fix the problem and I can´t find anything on the web.

Comment: Does it work if you rename the C:/Python34 folder? QGIS needs its own Python 2.7 to run.

Comment: How can I work with both versions ?

Comment: If my tip works, you would have to exchange the PYTHONPATH variable when you start QGIS, and restore it after quitting. QGIS is called with qgis.bat. That batch file changes the PATH and PYTHONHOME variable to avoid conflicts, but not PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Show the PYTHONPATH with and without the changes.

Comment: PYTHONPATH is not changed by QGIS, but maybe used.

Comment: I cannot understand actually how the PYTHONPATH works indeed. I must include the path to the folders where py files are ? or I have to include the path to the python.exe and pythonw.exe and all the python versions into my computer ?

Comment: For QGIS, you don't need PYTHONPATH at all. If you need it for Python 3.4, you better write a batch to include it when working with that. It should definitely not link to all python versions on your PC.

Comment: The problem with the dll lost is back again. I have reinstalled QGIS 2.4 in a new folder named QGIS-2.4 

Everything work fine but a soon as I restart windows the problem of lost dll is back
QGIS browser works, but not the desktop program

Comment: Have you tried renaming the Python34 folder?